# What is the use of copy constructor if all that it does can be done using '='?

Tags: c++

Copy ctor basically creates an object using a previously created object.
But what if we just create an object and then use '=' for element by element assignment. This even works if object is created dynamically. So what can the copy constructor do that the assignment operator cannot?

Comment: Construct an object.

Comment: Is the copy ctor more efficient? If so then why?

Comment: That's like asking whether a computer is more efficient than a lawnmower. More efficient at what? When? Makes no sense.

Comment: More efficient at copying the values of elements in comparision to the assignment operator.

Comment: I am not sure that the duplicate actually addresses the question. It explains the difference, but doesn't really provide an example why it is needed - why one can't simply default-construct an empty object and than copy already existing object to the newcomer. I will vote to reopen the question, if it get's reopen, will try to answer from this perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of good reasons to use copy constructor rather than default constructing an empty object and than assigning the new object to some already existing object.

### Reason one. Const-correctness

First, let's play a devil advocate and consider the case when it doesn't matter:

```
struct X {
    int i;
};

X x;
x.i = 10;
X y; 
y = x;  // Option 1 
X y(x) // Option 2
```

In the example above, there is really no difference between option 1 and option 2, other than better readabilty and code reasoning. But, what if we would like to make our `y` object a `const` object - because we don't want it to change over it's lifetime? Than option 1 would not be valid:

```
const X y;
y = x; // Compilation error!
```

So, even on the simplest example, we can tell that even for very simple types, differentiating between assignment and copy-construction is very important for **const-correctness**. (There could be other examples for the same point).

### Reason 2. Code efficiency

Next comes performance implications. Let's consider a very broken and incorrect implementation of string class (illustration only, has no place in life other than that):

```
struct VeryBrokenString {
    char* buffer;
    VeryBrokenString() buffer(new char[1]) { strcpy(buffer, ""); }
    ~VeryBrokenString() { delete[] buffer; }
    VeryBrokerString& operator= (const VeryBrokenString& rhs) {
        delete[] buffer;
        buffer = new [strlen(rhs.buffer) + 1];
        strcpy(buffer, rhs.buffer);
        return *this;
    }
   VeryBrokenString(const VeryBrokenString& rhs) {
        buffer = new [strlen(rhs.buffer) + 1];
        strcpy(buffer, rhs.buffer);
   }
};

VeryBrokenString one; // init it somehow :)
VeryBrokenString two;
two = one; // Option 1
VeryBrokenString two(one); //Option 2
```

In the example above, option 1 leads to duplication of efforts - the buffer is first allocated, and than deallocated, only to be allocated again. In option 2 the buffer is allocated only once. So, second point: copy-constructors help to generate **more efficient code**.

### Reason 3. Correctness

Now, let's consider above broken string. While it is wrong on many levels, one particularly bad piece of code is it's assignment operator. It deletes original buffer, and than allocates a new one, copying data from `rhs`. Two major issues are that if `rhs` is the same as `this`, there will be nothing to copy from after deletion. And the second problem is that if for any reason new allocation throws an exception (run out of memory, for example), we would already loose the the original buffer. While the first problem can be addressed with a check for self-assignment (`if (&rhs == this) return *this;`) the second could not be easily addressed in a straightforward way. One can read about how to write assignment operators in different articles, but agreed approach would be (for this class) somewhere along following lines:

```
// Rest of BrokenString remains the same
NotSoBrokenString& operator= (const NotSoBrokenString& rhs) {
    NotSoBrokenString temp(rhs);
    char* const buf = buffer;
    buffer = temp.buffer;
    temp.buffer = buf;
}
```

This is much better, since all the allocation is within `temp` constructor. If it fails - throws an exception - the original buffer remains valid and usable. (It also addresses the problem of self-assignment - no harm would be done when `this` is the same as `rhs`, albeit of slight inefficiency). 
So, point number three - assignment operators are often done in terms of copy constructors!

Now this answer is becoming quite big, so I won't have an example for this, but often the semantics of the class allows it to be copy-constructed, but not assigned.

### Conclusion

The benefits of copy-constructors used over assignment operators include const-correctness, efficiency, code correctness and support for non-trivial semantics.